# Remove "save in password manager" option in gpg pinentry

Tags: gpg, pinentry, seahorse

I have some libreoffice documents stored with "encrypt with gpg key" option.  Today I was quite surprised when the document opened without requesting a passphrase.  Eventually I found an entry for my gpg key in the system key and password manager, Seahorse, where the passphrase could be displayed.

I conclude that I must have accidentally checked the "save in password manager" box in the pinentry dialog when I logged in the last time.  A small mistake exposed a confidential document and my most important password.

This appears to be the same problem as [here:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707788/gnome-keyring-pinentry-gpg-key-password-saved-indefinitely-after-ubuntu-15-10-up)
but in my case free access to the document and the Seahorse entry survive beyond the timeout defined in `gpg-agent.conf`, after

```
echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent
```

and even after a reboot.

I tried `gnupg.conf` no-allow-external-cache option, which causes a different pinentry dialog without the checkbox, but then the private key password is not accepted.

Is there a way to remove or disable that checkbox in the pinentry dialog?

My system:

MX-linux 18.3_x64  December 15  2017
base: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.18

Answer (score 3):

Placing `no-allow-external-cache` in `gpg-agent.conf` eliminates the checkbox.